# Class can't reach int function from main C++

Tags: c++

I'm writing a program, however for some reason I can't reach the gameplay function from main, except I just get the following errors:

```
20:23: error: expected primary-expression before ']' token
```

Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int gameplay (int suitcase[], ofstream outputFile)
{
    cout << "Here?";
    return 0;
}
int main()
{
    const int ARRAY_SIZE = 10;
    int suitcase [ARRAY_SIZE] = {1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000, 1000000, 0, 0, 0};
    ofstream outputFile;
    outputFile.open ("players.txt");
    gameplay(suitcase[], outputFile);
    outputFile.close ();

    return 0;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Your problem isn't that you can't reach the function. I posted an explanation as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `main()` function call syntax of `gameply` is wrong!

```
gameplay(suitcase[], outputFile);
```

should be just:

```
gameplay(suitcase, outputFile);
                 ^
                  removed []
```

`[]` needed in function declaration but not at the time when you call function.

Answer (score 0):

Since you already defined suitcase as an array, you shouldn't have to say suitcase[] when you pass it into the function. (or refer to it anywhere else, for that matter)

```
gameplay(suitcase[], outputFile);
```

should just be:

```
gameplay(suitcase, outputFile);
```

This should work!